# FileMapping - как понять, когда читать?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Попробовал передавать данные между двумя приложениями через FileMapping - все работает.

Но тут возник вопрос: когда я из одного приложения пишу в общую память, как мне во втором приложении то понять, а когда мне читать ?
Если бы это была передача данных через сокеты к примеру то тут понятно - делаю условно send, на приемной стороне срабатывает callback по пришедшему запросу, а вот с FileMapping - не понятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, заведите именованное событие CreateEvent. Пишущий процесс, закончив запись, устанавливает событие SetEvent. Читатель ждёт события WaitForSingleObject (в отдельном потоке, если ему есть чем ещё заняться). Это одна из простых схем синхронизации, на деле, скорее всего, понадобится что-то посложнее

Почитайте Рихтера